# BQ - INSERT without listing columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 BQ tables, very wide ones in terms of number of columns.  Note all the table columns are made nullable for flexibility

Table A - 1000 cols - Superset of Bs cols
Table B - 500 cols - Subset of As cols - exactly named/typed as above cols

So rows in Bs table data should be insertable into A, where anything column not inserted just gets a null.  i.e 500 cols get a value, remaining 500 get a default null as not present in the insert.

So as these tables are very wide, enumerating all the columns in an insert statement would take forever and be a maintence nightmare.

Is there a way in standard SQL to insert without listing the columns names in the the insert statement, whereby its automagically name matched?

So I want to be able to do this really and have the columns from B matched to A for each row inserted?  If not is there any other way I am not seeing that could help with this?

thanks!

```
INSERT INTO
  `p.d.A` (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `p.d.B` )
```

I actually tried enumerating the columns to see if nesting worked and seems it doesnt?

```
INSERT INTO
      `p.d.A` (x, y.z) (
      SELECT
        x, y.z
      FROM
        `p.d.B` )
```

I cant just say (x,y) as y structs from the dff tables arent exactly the same BQ complains structs dont match exact.....hence why I was trying y.z ?

Comment: Given the size of the tables, would creating a new table with a join not achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The tables are populated from seperate ingest methods so need these tables to remain as is.  Not ideal but is what it is for now.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, easy!

Prepare dummy table `p.d.b_` using below select

```
SELECT * FROM `p.d.a` WHERE FALSE
```

(Note, even though result will be empty table - above will scan whole table a - this is required just once - so should be Okey - if not you can script this once and just create this table from script)

Ok, so now instead of using

```
SELECT * FROM `p.d.b`
```

you will use

```
SELECT * FROM `p.d.b*`
```

and this will make a trick for you (it did for me :o)

P.S. Of course I assume you will make sure there is no other tables with names starting with `b` (or whatever real name is) in that dataset

Comment: Hi Mikhail - sorry im being daft not totally following this.  I tried added the * (you know so many tricks :) is that a type and meant to be b_?  Why the need to create a dummy table anyway if the table is alreadythere.  Excuse my ignorance if its obvious!  If you could do the full SQL with insert that would help too.  Im trying even full qualifying every attribute as a test, and seems I cant do nested '.' notation in an insert of am I missing something (refer updated example above)

Comment: In reference to the insert using nested, I can use a select struct<> () to build the data up then insert that....was curious though if you could use struct 'dot' notation in the insert itself

Comment: have you tried to do literally what I suggested? exactly as it is in my answer but just replacing `p.s.a` and `p.d.b` with your real table names? and IMPORTANT - don't miss underscore after `b`!

Comment: 1) dummy table needed to hold targeted schema while having no rows at all 2) `*` is a wildcard that `adds` that dummy table to select statement and `enforces` needed schema even if original `b` table are missing some of fields 3) have not tested above approach with records/structs - but it sure works with primitive data types :o) my suggestion - try to reproduce this approach for simple scenario and then move to real case

Comment: Hi Mikhail - sorry been really sick and out of action.  Will get back to this soon thanks for checking up :)

Comment: take care and get better